# How to Delete Duplicate Rows Based on Priority and Highest End Date in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, case, sql-delete, window-functions

I have a database of around 850k rows of data that has a list of customers with Dates and Reference Numbers. The data has been put together through the use of a number of CSV files therefore I have a lot of duplicate data within the database and I am now trying to delete these based on a set of Rules. The one thing that you will notice that is consistent within the dataset is the reference number, as the customer will each have a unique ref number no matter how many times their record has been added into the database.

I have put together a sample set of data to try and see if I can build a logic and the following is my create and insert statements:

```
CREATE TABLE `rules_sample` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 `Name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `Start_Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `End_Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `Ref_No` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `Filename` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL
);


INSERT INTO `rules_sample` (`id`, `Name`, `Start_Date`, `End_Date`, `Ref_No`, `Filename`) VALUES
(172251, 'Mr. Humpty Dumpty', '2018-01-01', '2018-01-30', '110001239', 'Unknown'),
(956757, 'Humpty Dumpty', '2018-02-01', '2019-02-01', '110001239', 'Main 1'),
(957765, 'Humpty Dumpty', '2017-02-01', '2018-02-01', '110001239', 'Main 1'),
(958415, 'Humpty Dumpty', '2016-02-01', '2017-01-31', '110001239', 'Main 1'),
(958635, 'Mr Humpty Dumpty', '2014-11-13', '2015-11-13', '110001239', 'Main 1'),
(1104524, 'Mr. Humpty Dumpty', '2018-01-30', '2017-08-03', '110001239', 'Unknown'),
(1104662, 'Humpty Dumpty', '2018-02-01', '2017-08-05', '110001239', 'Unknown'),
(1114207, 'Humpty Dumpty', '2017-02-01', '2018-02-01', '110001239', 'Unknown'),
(1114504, 'Mr Humpty Dumpty', '2014-11-13', '2015-11-13', '110001239', 'Unknown'),
(1348915, 'Mr. Humpty Dumpty', '2018-01-30', '2019-01-30', '110001239', 'Other_Data'),
(92625, 'Mickey Mouse', '2018-08-09', '2018-08-08', '110003936', 'Unknown'),
(93713, 'Mr&Mrs M Mouse', '2017-06-23', '2019-06-22', '110003936', 'Unknown'),
(94978, 'Mickey Mouse', '2018-08-09', '2020-08-08', '110003936', 'Unknown'),
(847136, 'Mickey Mouse', '2020-08-08', '2020-08-08', '110003936', 'Data'),
(847193, 'Mickey Mouse', '2018-08-08', '2018-08-08', '110003936', 'Data'),
(847379, 'Mr&Mrs M Mouse', '2019-06-22', '2019-06-22', '110003936', 'Data'),
(858126, 'Mr&Mrs M Mouse', '2019-08-08', '2019-08-08', '110003936', 'Data'),
(1288753, 'Mr&Mrs M Mouse', '2018-06-22', '2019-06-22', '110003936', 'ABC Services'),
(930743, '.', '2020-08-14', '2020-08-14', '116000074', 'ABC Services'),
(930980, '.', '2020-07-22', '2020-07-22', '116000074', 'ABC Services'),
(931226, '.', '2020-06-30', '2020-06-30', '116000074', 'ABC Services'),
(931804, '.', '2020-05-13', '2020-05-13', '116000074', 'ABC Services'),
(932008, '.', '2020-05-03', '2020-05-03', '116000074', 'ABC Services'),
(932230, '.', '2020-04-26', '2020-04-26', '116000074', 'ABC Services'),
(932644, '.', '2020-04-10', '2020-04-10', '116000074', 'ABC Services'),
(933416, '.', '2020-03-17', '2020-03-17', '116000074', 'ABC Services'),
(933591, '.', '2020-03-08', '2020-03-08', '116000074', 'ABC Services'),
(933887, '.', '2020-02-27', '2020-02-27', '116000074', 'ABC Services'),
(934965, '.', '2020-01-21', '2020-01-21', '116000074', 'ABC Services');
```

Now my rules are based on 2 factors, 1) the highest end date 2) priority list based on the filename (shown below).

```
Priority | Filename
1 | Main 1
2 | Data
3 | ABC Services
4 | Other_Data
5 | Unknown
```

The first steps I have taken is to write the following code in order to rank the End Date:

```
SELECT 
    T1.*,
    Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY Ref_No ORDER BY End_Date DESC) rank
FROM 
    rules_sample T1
    ;
```

This gives me the following output:

```
id  Name    Start_Date  End_Date    Mpan_MPR    Data_Source rank
956757  Humpty Dumpty   2018-02-01  2019-02-01  110001239   Main 1 1
1348915 Mr. Humpty Dumpty   2018-01-30  2019-01-30  110001239   Other_Data 2
957765  Humpty Dumpty   2017-02-01  2018-02-01  110001239   Main 1 3
1114207 Humpty Dumpty   2017-02-01  2018-02-01  110001239   Unknown 4
172251  Mr. Humpty Dumpty   2018-01-01  2018-01-30  110001239   Unknown 5
1104662 Humpty Dumpty   2018-02-01  2017-08-05  110001239   Unknown 6
1104524 Mr. Humpty Dumpty   2018-01-30  2017-08-03  110001239   Unknown 7
958415  Humpty Dumpty   2016-02-01  2017-01-31  110001239   Main 1 8
958635  Mr Humpty Dumpty    2014-11-13  2015-11-13  110001239   Main 9
1114504 Mr Humpty Dumpty    2014-11-13  2015-11-13  110001239   Unknown 10
94978   Mickey Mouse    2018-08-09  2020-08-08  110003936   Unknown 1
847136  Mickey Mouse    2020-08-08  2020-08-08  110003936   Data 2
858126  Mr&Mrs M Mouse  2019-08-08  2019-08-08  110003936   Data 3
93713   Mr&Mrs M Mouse  2017-06-23  2019-06-22  110003936   Unknown 4
847379  Mr&Mrs M Mouse  2019-06-22  2019-06-22  110003936   Data 5
1288753 Mr&Mrs M Mouse  2018-06-22  2019-06-22  110003936   ABC Services 6
92625   Mickey Mouse    2018-08-09  2018-08-08  110003936   Unknown 7
847193  Mickey Mouse    2018-08-08  2018-08-08  110003936   Data 8
930743  .   2020-08-14  2020-08-14  116000074   ABC Services 1
930980  .   2020-07-22  2020-07-22  116000074   ABC Services 2
931226  .   2020-06-30  2020-06-30  116000074   ABC Services 3
931804  .   2020-05-13  2020-05-13  116000074   ABC Services 4
932008  .   2020-05-03  2020-05-03  116000074   ABC Services 5
932230  .   2020-04-26  2020-04-26  116000074   ABC Services 6
932644  .   2020-04-10  2020-04-10  116000074   ABC Services 7
933416  .   2020-03-17  2020-03-17  116000074   ABC Services 8
933591  .   2020-03-08  2020-03-08  116000074   ABC Services 9
933887  .   2020-02-27  2020-02-27  116000074   ABC Services 10
934965  .   2020-01-21  2020-01-21  116000074   ABC Services 11
```

Now where I am struggling is how to include the priority list into my code. My final output should look like the following:

```
id  Name    Start_Date  End_Date    Mpan_MPR    Data_Source
956757  Humpty Dumpty   2018-02-01  2019-02-01  110001239   Main 1
847136  Mickey Mouse    2020-08-08  2020-08-08  110003936   Data
930743  .       2020-08-14  2020-08-14  116000074   ABC Services
```

I will explain the breakdown of how my final output is worked out:

For 110001239, it's quite straightforward, the End_Date with rank 1 has the filename Main 1 which has a Priority of 1 from the list so the rest of the data should get deleted.

110003936 is a bit more tricky as the highest End_Date has the filename Unknown but the priority for this is 5, now the 2nd End_Date is the same End_Date as the first one and the Filename for this is Data which has a priority of 2 therefore the row with rank 2 should be kept and the rest be removed.

116000074, is straightforward as rank 1 of End_Date should be kept as we only have 1 filename across all records.

One of the key things to note is the End_Date overrides the Priority of the Filename. My code will need to account for records where I might have all filenames within the same Ref_No but this will go based on the highest End Date.

Hope that all makes sense.

Comment: It's great that you've provided sample data and a desired result, but you could express this problem far more succinctly.

Comment: Apologies Strawberry, I tried to keep it as brief as I could, but will make sure, I don't overcomplicate my future questions.

Answer (score 0):

If I followed you correctly, you could use [string function `field()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) as a second sorting criteria in the window function:

```
row_number() over (
    partition by ref_no 
    order by 
        end_date desc, 
        field(filename, 'Main 1', 'Data', 'ABC Services', 'Other_data', 'Unknown')
) rank
```

`field()` returns the index of the first matching value in the list - so if `filename` has value `'Data'` for example, it would return 2.

There is a little trap in the fact that `field()` returns `0` if the value does not match anything in the list. If that may happen, then you might want to sort in reverse order:

```
row_number() over (
    partition by ref_no 
    order by 
        end_date desc, 
        field(filename, 'Unknown', 'Other_data', 'ABC Services', 'Data', 'Main 1') desc
) rank
```

Comment: Thanks GMB, will have a look through this and come back to you. Thank you once again.

Comment: GMB rank seems to have worked. Is there anyway for me to get the value of 'Data' to have a rank of 1 instead of 2, based on the priority list as the End_Date values are the same therefore 'Data' should be ranked 1.

Comment: @MichaelOwen: if you  want `'Data'`before `'Main 1'`, then: `row_number() over (
    partition by ref_no 
    order by 
        end_date desc, 
        field(filename, 'Unknown', 'Other_data', 'ABC Services',  'Main 1', 'Data') desc
) rank`

Comment: Sorry GMB, its more for the Ref_No 110003936 as Unknown is showing as Rank 1 and Data as Rank 2 as the End_Date's are the same but as the Priority for Data is higher than Unknown thats why this should be higher.